# Java skip XML subtree when parse error

Tags: java, xml

So i want to parse an XML StreamSource containing a collection of similar objects.
However, the stream sometimes contains unsupported characters that make the parsing process fail.

Now what i'd like to do is to skip the subtree that contains the invalid character and parse the rest.

For instance, let's say the XML contains a collection of users each of which has a name and stats attributes (followers, posts, etc.) and one of them has a name that contains an invalid character. I'd like to be able to skip the same but still be able to parse the rest of the user object.

Is there a way to do that? Do you need extra information? Please let me know.

FYI: i'm using a javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller and a JAXBContext to parse the stream.

Comment: What constitutes an invalid character? Are you talking about one of the handful of characters which are invalid to represent (even with escaping) in xml (such as ESC) or a character which your application considers invalid?

Comment: The ones that are invalid to represent in XML.

Comment: As best I can tell, none of the xml parsers shipped with the jre (sax, stax, or dom) will NOT parse invalid xml (though it has been a few years since I tried this). The only parse I found that would allow these characters (with escaping) was electric xml, which is fairly difficult to track down now.

Comment: What about a filter between the original source and the reader feeding the unmarshaller?

Comment: Well that's clever! Thanks @laune, i'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

All of the document based parsers I am aware of will fail in the validation phase so you are going to need to use an event based parser (SAX).  I've had success with TagSoup which is a forgiving xml parser.

http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/

Comment: Actually the filter between the source and the reader fix did the trick.